# "-ic versus -ical" what's the difference in meaning between adjectives ending in -ic or -ical?

Tags: suffixes, ic-ical, affixes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it “geometric” but “theoretical”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/why-is-it-geometric-but-theoretical)
>   [“Ironic” vs. “ironical”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5015/ironic-vs-ironical)
>   [“Comic” vs. “comical”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57060/comic-vs-comical)
>   [“Historic” vs. “historical”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72914/what-is-the-difference-between-words-like-historic-and-historical-and-inst)

What's the difference for instance between *ironic/ironical, rhythmic/rhythmical, historic/historical, comic/comical, economic/economical*? If these adjectives are identical in meaning why the need for the different endings?

Comment: We have a [whole tag](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ic-ical?sort=votes&pagesize=50) dedicated to the difference between *-ic* and *-ical*. With some [spectacular answers](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/why-is-it-geometric-but-theoretical/6600#6600), too.